# Assigining functions in a for loop

Tags: r

I am working on a package and want to make some functions that return very similar results. I thought it would be slick to assign the function names in a for-loop but I am not getting the desired results. The name updates each time but the value seems to only use the last value of `i`.

I'm not sure what might be going on.

```r
return_letter <- function(i){
  letters[i]
}


for(i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste0("fn_", i), function() return_letter(i))
}


fn_1() # expect "a", get "c"
fn_2() # expect "b", get "c"
fn_3() # expect "c", get "c"


rm(list = ls(pattern = "^fn_"))
```

For context, the package deals with color names and I want to return palettes for reds, blues, greens, etc.

Comment: This seems more "bad practice" than "slick". It's hard to imagine this going anywhere in a package---the codewould need to be executed to create the functions, and then they would be created in the users environment, not the package namespace, meaning they couldn't be used inside the package and would overwrite any functions the user already had that happened to have the same name. An actually slick way to do something like this would be to use [functionals](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html), which is what is done, e.g., by `colorRamp` and `colorRampPalette`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is creating the functions as string, parsing and then evaluating

```
for(i in 1:3)
     eval(parse(text = paste0("fn_", i, " <- function()letters[", i, "]"))) #fixed mistake. Last i should be outside quotes.
```

However, it seems like quite an inefficient way of handling colour picking. The `colourpicker` package, allows to selecting colours through a shiny widget. One might find interesting source code.

If the point is to store colours, for use within various function (such as shiny widgets), using an encapsulated environment or an object might be a safer or better way to go. Basically storing colours within a list as the colours are chosen for later. Using an R6 or S4 object (the prior is in most cases simpler and more intuitive to work with), would be one way to go in this case. (I'd suggest looking and trying the examples from `?R6::R6Class` in this case.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The solution still brings back the last iteration (all "c"s). Thoughts as to why?

Comment: Oh i see that i've quoted the later i. Both I's withiin `paste0(--)` should be without quotes. The reason why it would return c, is that i is stored in the global environment. (The last value of `i` after the for loop is 3, and this wil lbe saved in `globalenv()`, which will be used in the function) I have updated my answer fixing this mistake.